# Wildfly / Undertow : Multiple aliases for one host

Tags: jakarta-ee, virtualhost, wildfly, undertow

In **standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml**, I've declared the following host, that **works**

```
<host name="webhost" alias="gateway.example.com" />
```

When I try to add another alias, I'm given Error 404.

```
<host name="webhost" alias="gateway.example.com www.gateway.example.com"/>
```

The [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow+(web)+subsystem+configuration) says list of aliases is whitespace separated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug in documentation. It is comma separated list of hosts not white space separated.

example would be

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost, some.host" >
```

I also fixed documentation to to address this